# Error while inline editing in material-table + reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Material-Table along-with ReactJS to create data-table. The table properly loads and displays the data properly but once I edit the data, I get the below error in developer console

[image]

Below is my code for Material Table

```
            <MaterialTable
              title={tbl_title}
              columns={datatable.columns}
              data={datatable.data}
              options={tableOptions}
              editable={{
                onRowAdd: newData =>
                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      {
                        const data = datatable.data;
                        data.push(newData);
                        setTable({ data }, () => resolve());

                      }
                      resolve()
                    }, 1000);
                  }),
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      {
                        const data = datatable.data;
                        const index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                        data[index] = newData;
                        setTable({ data }, () => resolve());
                      }
                      resolve()
                    }, 1000)
                }),
              }}
            />
```

I am just using the same code sample from the provider with small modification to meet React Functional Component pattern. It would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction.

An older issue for similar error [Github Issue: 400](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/400) is listed but has no guidance for the issue.

[EDIT]

I am not sure if this helps, but I am seeing a very unusual thing with last modified date for all files after a fresh install of the dependency.
[image: Last Modified date is dated to old date compared to current date]

Would this affect somehow the functioning of the dependency package?

Further, error details while editing/adding row
[image]

Code changes I used to fix the error in above image

File: node_modules/material-table/dist/components/m-table-body.js:113

```
return renderData.map(function (data, index) {
    if (typeof(data.tableData) != "undefined") {

      if (data.tableData.hasOwnProperty("editing")) {
        return React.createElement(_this.props.components.EditRow, {
          columns: _this.props.columns.filter(function (columnDef) {
            return !columnDef.hidden;
          }),
          components: _this.props.components,
          data: data,
          icons: _this.props.icons,
          localization: (0, _objectSpread2["default"])({}, MTableBody.defaultProps.localization.editRow, _this.props.localization.editRow, {
            dateTimePickerLocalization: _this.props.localization.dateTimePickerLocalization
          }),
          key: index,
          mode: data.tableData.editing,
          options: _this.props.options,
          isTreeData: _this.props.isTreeData,
          detailPanel: _this.props.detailPanel,
          onEditingCanceled: _this.props.onEditingCanceled,
          onEditingApproved: _this.props.onEditingApproved,
          getFieldValue: _this.props.getFieldValue
        });
      } else {
        return React.createElement(_this.props.components.Row, {
          components: _this.props.components,
          icons: _this.props.icons,
          data: data,
          index: index,
          key: "row-" + data.tableData.id,
          level: 0,
          options: _this.props.options,
          localization: (0, _objectSpread2["default"])({}, MTableBody.defaultProps.localization.editRow, _this.props.localization.editRow),
          onRowSelected: _this.props.onRowSelected,
          actions: _this.props.actions,
          columns: _this.props.columns,
          getFieldValue: _this.props.getFieldValue,
          detailPanel: _this.props.detailPanel,
          path: [index + _this.props.pageSize * _this.props.currentPage],
          onToggleDetailPanel: _this.props.onToggleDetailPanel,
          onRowClick: _this.props.onRowClick,
          isTreeData: _this.props.isTreeData,
          onTreeExpandChanged: _this.props.onTreeExpandChanged,
          onEditingCanceled: _this.props.onEditingCanceled,
          onEditingApproved: _this.props.onEditingApproved,
          hasAnyEditingRow: _this.props.hasAnyEditingRow,
          treeDataMaxLevel: _this.props.treeDataMaxLevel
        });
      }

    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox to reproduce this?

Comment: @Domino987, I am unable to reproduce it on sandbox.

Comment: hmh that makes it difficult to fix your problem, can you make sure that all props are the same as in the example. Especially with console.log or debugging

Comment: @Domino987 I have made edits on the question nad added 2 more imagesunder EDIT section to help understand. I also tried debugging the error and I had to edit the code as mentioned above. Does this help in any way? Am I working in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the code of your columns?

Comment: @Domino987 is it the code that you are requesting when adding or updating rows? If yes, It is already above within <MaterialTable ... /> Initial data load has no issues. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Can you show the code for columns={datatable.columns} (the object)?

Comment: @Domino987  

{
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "Team",
      "field": "team",
      "lookup": {
        "dev": "Dev Team",
        "ops": "Ops Team",
        "hr": "HR Team"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Month",
      "field": "month",
      "type": "numeric"
    },
    {
      "title": "# of people in team",
      "field": "teamsize",
      "type": "numeric"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "team": "dev",
      "month": "1",
      "teamsize": "5"
    },
    {
      "team": "ops",
      "month": "1",
      "teamsize": "2"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Domino987 does the object for datatable columns help you in any way?

Comment: I thought it might but it does not. Can you reproduce that in a codepen?

Comment: OK, now sandbox is a bit tough for me as well. I will do my best to provide you with one. Based on your experience with the dependency, there is some issue with my implementation, right?

Comment: Yes I ha e it in several production apps and I am the second most contributor to the project so I would say I have a good grasp of it ;)

Comment: @Domino987, I think you got my question wrong there. I was asking if from your experience with material-table and all the details provided, do you think the issue might be in the way I am using material-table in my project? 

Also, Is it possible for you to join the chatroom - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203970/material-table

Comment: Did u had a solution for this??